# Mutli-column unique rails index not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unique, multiple-columns, compound-index

I'm struggling to figure this one out:

I have a `User` model with an email and a secondary email that they can use to login. A user should not have the same email/secondary email as another user. The two columns should also be mutually unique.

**What's happening**

However, my indexes only validate uniqueness in their own column. So a user cannot have the same email as another user, and they cannot have the same secondary email as another secondary email.

---

The index that ensures the two columns are unique with themselves and adds the unique index for email and secondary email

### [image: The index that ensures the two columns are unique with themselves]

But the indexes dont work across the two columns
[image: But I should not be able to have another user's email as my secondary email]

**What's expected**

A user should not be able to use an email that exists in the database as a email or secondary email.

---

`migration.rb`

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.string :secondary_email
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :users, [:email, :secondary_email], unique: true
    add_index :users, [:secondary_email, :email], unique: true
    add_index :users, :secondary_email, unique: true
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

I've tried all combinations of the index arrangements. Without the bottom single indexes, a user could have the same `email`s as long as their `secondary_email`s were unique.

Comment: *A user should not be able to use an email that exists in the database as a email or secondary email* This applies for `secondary_email` too?

Comment: Yeah. So a user shouldnt be able to add a secondary email if it is already added as someone else's email or secondary email.

Answer (score 0):

> A user should not be able to use an email that exists in the database
>   as a email or secondary email

The only way I can think of *to avoid such cases* is by doing *custom validations*. Something like the below should work

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :verify_unique_email_or_secondary_email

  def verify_unique_email_or_secondary_email
    if User.exists?("email = ? OR secondary_email = ?", email,email)
      errors.add(:email, 'Email or Secondary Email has already been taken')
    end
  end
end
```